# “Overflow” in Extended Euclidean Algorithm

Tags: ds.algorithms, nt.number-theory

Sorry if I'm mistaken with the place to ask the question (maybe I should go to stackoverflow.com/mathoverflow.net?).

I wonder if there is a proof that when evaluating extended Euclidean algorithm the Bézout's coefficients (that is *s* and *t* in identity *as* + *bt* = gcd(*a*, *b*)) will not exceed some reasonable values (depending on a, b, I guess). In particular implementation on some general-purpose programming language I'm interested in overflow correctness of the program.

To be precise I can mention that I use Victor Shoup's description of the algorithm (4.2 in his book “[A Computational Introduction to  Number Theory and Algebra](http://shoup.net/ntb/)” freely available from his homepage).

Comment: I think this is definitely within scope.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is called the [Bézout's identity/lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) (not to be confused with [Bézout's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem) in algebraic geometry), which states:

> **Lemma.** For every integers $a,b \neq 0$, $\gcd(a,b) = ax + by$ for some integers $x,y$. Also, we may assume $|x| \leq |b|$ and $|y| \leq |a|$.

Proofs can be founded in standard algebra textbooks. Also you can prove it yourself by induction on the iterations of gcd process.

In general this is true in every [Euclidean domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain) $R$ with a multiplicative Euclidean function $f$. In the case here when $R = \mathbf{Z}$, we have $f(x) = |x|$ which is multiplicative.

Comment: You reference Wikipedia, but there is no such words: “Also, we may assume...”. Would you please name some “standard algebra textbook”? I looked into Rotman's First course in abstract algebra: there is description of Eucl. Algo, but there is no such bounds on coefficients. Same story in Shoup's book, which was referenced by me in my post.

Comment: Try Theorem 2.5 in the book by Keijo Ruohonen, http://math.tut.fi/~ruohonen/MC.pdf. If my momery is correct, the book by Fraleign has the lemma in the main text or in the exercises. http://www.amazon.com/First-Course-Abstract-Algebra-7th/dp/0201763907

Comment: Can this be generalized? say there exist a solution to $\gcd(a_1,\ldots,a_n) = \sum_{i} x_ia_i$ such that $\sum_{i}|x_i|\leq \sum_{i}|a_i|$?